# Angular Pagination using UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, json, html, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

My pagination links are not clickable, even worse the links display in text instead of bootstrap buttons ...

**- ANGULA JS CODE :** ...

```
...
.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','myresource','$route','$routeParams',function($scope,myresource,$route,$routeParams){
        // console logs when I click on pagination link ...
        $scope.pageChanged = function(){
            console.log("Loading Pagination ... ");
        };
        //gets data from JSON file 
        myresource.query(function(response){            
            $scope.users  = response;   
            myArray = $scope.users;
            //object for pagination instead of premitives 
            $scope.pagi = {
                currentPage:2,
                pageSize:5,
                objlength:myArray.length            
            }   
        });     
    }])
    //slice and filter desired number of items 
    .filter('PagiFilter', function(data,start){
        return data.slice(start);   
        });
```

- **HTML CODE :**

  UserID NumberDate of birthAgeGender

  ....

Comment: my html filter : <tr ng-repeat = 'user in users | filter:(pagi.currentPage-1) * pagi.pageSize | limitTo: pagi.pageSize | filter: searchTerm:strict'>
          <td>{{user.user}}</td>
        </table>
       </div>    
       
      </div>
      <div>
      <ul uib-pagination total-items='pagi.objlength' items-per-page = 'pagi.pageSize' ng-model='pagi.currentPage' data-ng-show='pagi.objlength' ng-change  = 'pageChanged()'> </ul>
      </div>

Comment: Did you add 'ui.bootstrap' or the required dependency to your module

Comment: I did add ui.bootstrap and bootstrap tpls...excuse my delayed response ... I crossed night trying to fix this problem

Comment: What could be making my link buttons not to show...?bootstrap only shows next , prev and boundaries but in text, not as buttons... This text are not click able however on ng-change, a function is called ... In addition am using a Json object/array, not a database, could that be the reason why ?

Comment: would it be possible to create a snippet illustrating the issue?

Comment: Did you try like this
 <uib-pagination class="pagination-sm" items-per-page="form.pageSize.size" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="form.page" ng-change="pageChanged()"></uib-pagination>